# Why apache throws 403 on index file after install?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions, configuration, ubuntu-10.10

I've just installed apache and php from sources using next commands:

```
./configure --prefix="/mnt/workspace/servers/web/apache-2.2.17" \
  --enable-info --enable-rewrite --enable-usertrack --enable-mime-magic
```

for apache and

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/mnt/workspace/servers/web/apache-2.2.17/bin/apxs \
  --prefix=/mnt/workspace/servers/web/apache-2.2.17/php \
  --with-config-file-path=/mnt/workspace/servers/web/apache-2.2.17/php \
  --with-mysql=mysqlnd
```

for php. After adjusting configuration (httpd.conf) and starting apache it gives a 403 response on http://localhost:8060/index.html (presuming that 8060 is used) request.

There are next directory settings in httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "/mnt/workspace/servers/web/apache-2.2.17/htdocs">
...
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
...
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

*It should be noted that I've got apache on a mounted (default auto mount configured while installing ubuntu) partition.*

**Log Files**

*Access log:*

```
::1 - - [12/Feb/2011:17:48:30 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202
::1 - - [12/Feb/2011:17:48:31 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 213
::1 - - [12/Feb/2011:17:48:48 +0200] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 403 212
::1 - - [12/Feb/2011:17:48:48 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 213
::1 - - [12/Feb/2011:17:49:03 +0200] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 403 212
::1 - - [12/Feb/2011:17:49:03 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 213
```

*Error log:*

```
[Sat Feb 12 18:59:13 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) PHP/5.3.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 12 18:59:22 2011] [error] [client ::1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
[Sat Feb 12 18:59:22 2011] [error] [client ::1] (13)Permission denied: access to /favicon.ico denied
[Sat Feb 12 18:59:36 2011] [error] [client ::1] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.html denied
```

Comment: What do your Apache error logs say?

Comment: Added logs, can't tell if they actually say something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was quiet awkward and I'm not sure what was going on. So basically because my account had no permissions on the mounted file system (ntfs) starting apache with sudo and having only root group able to access files made it impossible for any user to get a non 403 response. Formatting to ext4 did the trick. :D